# PERC 6/i Integrated RAID-0 from degraded and unconfigured RAID-10

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid10, lsi, megaraid

A 4-drive RAID10 setup was made on a `PERC 6/i Integrated` card.  One disk failed.  While waiting for a disk replacement, the controller card died.

Card was replaced, but unfortunately the foreign configurations were cleared by mistake, and so now the three drives appear as “Unconfigured(good)”.

In *theory* there should be two drives out of the four that could be re-setup as a temporary RAID-0, without data loss.

Checking the `MegaCLI` tool I see no obvious way to:

1. Identify the two drives that could be used to get that RAID-0 set;
2. Force two drives to be in a RAID-0 set without destroying data.

I wouldn't mind another solution (say, using software RAID tools) that'd allow using two good drives as a RAID-0 set.

Any way I can achieve this?

Alternatively, recreating the RAID10 array (in degraded mode) with the three functioning drives would suit me.

Comment: Why not just recreate the array and restore your data from backup?

Comment: @joeqwerty Because the data is *already* on the drives, and I'm describing a failure mode that's supposed, at least on paper, to be covered?